# Basic Iteration through hash maps

Tags: java

I have an issue searching a text file for an element in a hash map and returning a line of text from a  text file. For some reason I could only enter one word and it searches the file.  Instead of entering one word to search a file I want to enter a sentence. For example, if my text file contains " the professor is a good lady" and a user enters "how is the mentor" I want to search the input for  "mentor" and output the sentence "the professor is a good lady".

**additional information**

The program hangs if i enter some sentence, any sentence. But if i only enter one synonym word then the file is searched and a sentence is return. I want to enter a sentence and check that sentence for a synonym word

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    synonymMap= populateSynonymMap(); //populate the map
    System.out.println("Welcome To DataBase ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

     for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {

            String[] value = entry.getValue();
            if (Arrays.asList(value).contains(input)) {

                parseFile(entry.getKey());


                System.out.println("Have a good day!");
                break;
            }
        }


}
```

And here is my hash map method

```
    private static HashMap<String, String[]> populateSynonymMap() {
    responses.put("professor", new String[]{"instructor", "teacher", "mentor"});
    responses.put("book", new String[]{"script", "text", "portfolio"});
    responses.put("office", new String[]{"room", "post", "place"});
    responses.put("day", new String[]{"time",  "date"});
    responses.put("asssignment", new String[]{"homework", "current assignment "});
    responses.put("major", new String[]{"discipline", "focus"," study"});


    return responses;
}
```

Here is the parse file method

```
   public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            // break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So would you *also* output every sentence with "how" in it, and every sentence with "is", and every sentence with "the"? If not, how are you anticipating picking out "mentor" as the important word from "how is the mentor"?

Comment: how does the `parseFile` method function? can you upload the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing with

> Arrays.asList(value).contains(input)

method, you can define your you method which first splits input sentence into word and return you the word(String) if it is found in hashmap.

You can then pass the return String object into you

> parseFile

method

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the thing corrected! the problem was in the comparison of the `input` variable. So what I did is instead of comparing the string array to input using `.containt()` I have iterated over the array of string `value` and checked the `input.contains(v)` as below:

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {
        String[] value = entry.getValue();
        for(String v : value){
            if (input.contains(v)) {
                parseFile(entry.getKey());
                System.out.println("Have a good day!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tested it and found it to work correctly.

Comment: I want it to output the line containing professor. Professor is the main word and the other string objects that follows are the synonyms of that word. so i would like to print out the main word even if synonyms are inputted

Comment: @eggz I got your question wrong. I am correcting my answer now.

Comment: I get an error at    if ( entry.containsValue(input))

Comment: @Eggz could you elaborate about the error you are getting

Comment: Multiple markers at this line >> the method containsValue(string) is undefined for the type Map.entry<String,String[ ]>    if (entry.containsValue(input)) {

Comment: @Eggz Ok. Could you tell me what was the output you were getting before you made these modifications?

Comment: The program hangs if i enter some sentence, any sentence. But if i only enter one synonymn word then the file is searched and a sentence is return. I want to enter a sentence and check that sentence for a synonym word

Comment: Ok Now I perfectly understand your problem and am suggesting the corrections.

Comment: i apologize i fell asleep and the updated version still did not work.

Comment: @Eggz Finally I got it corrected. and I have tested it to be working.